# How do you print a dollar sign $ in Dart

Tags: syntax, variables, dart

I need to actually print a Dollar sign in Dart, ahead of a variable.  For example:

```dart
void main()
{
  int dollars=42;
  print("I have $dollars."); // I have 42.
}
```

I want the output to be:  I have $42.  How can I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `print("I have \$dollars."); ` ? (I don't actually know dart, I'm just guessing)

Comment: such characters are called escape characters

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Dart strings can be either raw or ... not raw (normal? cooked? interpreted? There isn't a formal name). I'll go with "interpreted" here, because it describes the problem you have.

In a raw string, "$" and "\" mean nothing special, they are just characters like any other.
In an interpreted string, "$" starts an interpolation and "\" starts an escape.

Since you want the interpolation for "$dollars", you can't use "$" literally, so you need to escape it:

```dart
int dollars = 42;
print("I have \$$dollars.");
```

If you don't want to use an escape, you can combine the string from raw and interpreted parts:

```dart
int dollars = 42;
print(r"I have $" "$dollars.");
```

Two adjacent string literals are combined into one string, even if they are different types of string.

Comment: There's an even more elaborate solution, that I don't want to recommend, but I think it's worth mentioning for completeness: using a string literal as the expression of a string interpolation: `print("I have ${r"$"}$dollars.")`. It's ... interesting, but I haven't found a case where it's more convenient than just having separate adjacent string literals.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer and congratulations on making it to 10,000!

Answer (score 21):

You can use a backslash to escape:

```dart
int dollars=42;
print("I have \$$dollars."); // I have $42.
```

When you are using literals instead of variables you can also use raw strings:

```dart
print(r"I have $42."); // I have $42.
```

Comment: Raw was my solution. I have a big token literal with lots of dollar signs in it, and I was going the PHP way ( single quotes won't interpolate ) but it's a little different here.