# How to change $ sign in Dart dynamically?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, syntax

I'd like to replace the dollar sign $ in a String and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898945/how-do-you-print-a-dollar-sign-in-dart?noredirect=1&lq=1) did so by manually putting a \ in front of the $ sign as shown:

```
String x = "I have $5"
\\changed to 
String x = "I have \$5"
```

What if there are a lot of $ signs in a string as shown below and you have to dynamically change them?

> "I have $5, he has $20, she has $40. The password is hre$1234o."

I tried the following to dynamically change them:

```
String x = "I have $5, he has $20, she has $40. The password is hre$1234o.";
print(x.replaceAll(RegExp(r'$'), '\$'));
```

But there is the following error:

```
lib/main.dart:4:21:
Error: A '$' has special meaning inside a string, and must be followed by an identifier or an expression in curly braces ({}).
String x = "I have $5, he has $20, she has $40. The password is hre$1234o.";
                    ^
lib/main.dart:4:32:
Error: A '$' has special meaning inside a string, and must be followed by an identifier or an expression in curly braces ({}).
String x = "I have $5, he has $20, she has $40. The password is hre$1234o.";
                               ^
lib/main.dart:4:45:
Error: A '$' has special meaning inside a string, and must be followed by an identifier or an expression in curly braces ({}).
String x = "I have $5, he has $20, she has $40. The password is hre$1234o.";
                                            ^
lib/main.dart:4:69:
Error: A '$' has special meaning inside a string, and must be followed by an identifier or an expression in curly braces ({}).
String x = "I have $5, he has $20, she has $40. The password is hre$1234o.";
                                                                    ^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

Is there a way to dynamically change many $ signs to \$?

The $ cannot be manually replaced in this case because the String data is obtained from the backend and there's no way to know where would the $ sign appear.

Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Will this string be static or it's from the server response?

Comment: It's a server response. I've just found and posted the solution, thanks for checking @SheetalGhori :)

Comment: "The $ cannot be manually replaced in this case because the String data is obtained from the backend and there's no way to know where would the $ sign appear."  This doesn't make sense.  If the string data is obtained from an external source, you shouldn't need to do anything.  String interpolation is *compile-time syntactic sugar*; it affects only string literals *in your code*.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution to this. Instead of replacing each $ with \$, I can simply put an r in front of the string as shown

```
x = "I have $5, he has $20, she has $40. The password is hre$1234o."
\\changed to
x = r"I have $5, he has $20, she has $40. The password is hre$1234o."
```

The r causes the string to ignore the $ sign in the string. Thanks!